# How to add hash to bundle name in SSR react app

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have ssr app and server has code (simplified)

```js
 const content = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

 return `
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${content}</div>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
```

The problems is, that a want to add hash to bundle.js which is composed by webpack. I can edit webpack config which compiles bundle so it will hash in the name, but server code has no idea about dynamic name of bundle.

I have two solutions:

1. Add plugin to webpack so it will make template (for example `.hbs`) file with bundle name already inserted in it and then modify it on server to insert additional data (like meta, content and so on). I don't like this solution because it will require reading file on every request
2. Set dynamical ENV variable in webpack config which compiles client, add it to bundle name and then access in ENV on server

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
process.env.BUILD_HASH = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
const BUILD_HASH = process.env.BUILD_HASH
console.log('building client')

const config = {
  output: {
    filename: `bundle_${BUILD_HASH}.js`,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  }
};
```

I don't like this solution because it requires to set ENV var dynamically

Comment: I feel like the whole "flow" is a bit wrong. Usually how SSR works, is that you let webpack build a regular react build, which will output an `index.html` and all `js` + `css` files which are correctly included in the `script` and `style` tags attached to the HTML body/head. You can tell webpack here already to use a hash for the scripts and css.

Then on your server, you get that specific `index.html` during a GET request (or crone job) and let SSR run on the `root` div, and replace the empty body with the `renderToString` result.

You don't have to worry about the script include at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend, use this plugin and be happy  
https://github.com/ztoben/assets-webpack-plugin#configuration

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this plugin [react-ssr-webpack-plguin](https://github.com/wood1986/react-ssr-webpack-plugin). It supports filename with hash, subresource integrity and inline the JS to html. It is done in one process with a tiny configuration. It also has live reload on save when both server and client JS have changes. You can this [video](https://youtu.be/3oixZZHacjQ) as well